# Which game is more advantageous?

Tags: binomial-distribution, dice

I got a pretty simple problem but I'm not sure about my solution.

Game $A$: We roll a fair die 4 times. If we get the "6" at least one time, we win.

Game $B$: We roll a fair die 8 times. If we get the "6" at least two times, we win.

Which game is more advantageous for us ?

I calculated the first moments which are $\frac{4}{6}$ for game $A$ and $\frac{8}{6}$ for game $B$.

While the expected Value of $B$ is higher than $A$, the probability for $P(X\geq1)$ in game $A$ equals 0.5177 and for game $B$, $P(X\geq2)=0.3953$. This shows that game $B$ is worse than game $A$.

Which solution is right ?

And another question with regard to this problem:

If you multiply the number of trials (here 4 × 2) and the number of minimum successes (here 1 × 2) by a factor $c$ (here 2) why doesn't the probability equal the same number multiplied by $c$ ?

Comment: What is the payoff for each outcome?

Comment: There is no payoff it just asks which game is more advantageous

Comment: But what notion of advantage do you then use? Just to see which one you're more likely to win?

Comment: Yes, the game with the higher probability of winning, which seems to be A

Comment: But why cant we say that P(X = x) for X ~ Bin(n,p) = P(X = 2x) for X ~ Bin(2n,p) ?

Comment: I see only one solution where you make a conclusion about which game is better.  What is the other one you are asking about?

Comment: probably we would like to have answer to $P(X_{Bin(4, 1/6)}=1) ??? P(X_{Bin(8, 1/6)}=2)$

Comment: as for second question for factor $c=2$ $P(game\, with\, c=2) = 2*(P(X_{Bin(4,1/6)}=2)*P(X_{Bin(4,1/6)}=0)) + P(game\, with\, c=1)^2$ or something quite close to this equality

Comment: Ultimately, without clear criteria the question cannot be reasonably answered that I can tell. Or you can give conditioned answers: Under conditions X,Y,Z , game A is advantageous, under other conditions, B is more advantageous.

Comment: Winning seems clearly defined for each variant of the game. Those rules for winning have to do with probabilities of various outcomes, not directly related to the binomial means. // I seem to recall this is a variant of one of the early betting games solved by probability pioneers (Bernoulli, Laplace, etc.) but I can't immediately find an exact reference, does anyone recall that?

Comment: @whuber the other one is "I calculated the first moments which are 4/6 for game A and 8/6 for game B." So the contrast (between two solutions) is in game B getting a higher mean number of dice rolls with a six, but on the other hand the probability to win is lower. (the trick in this difference that for game B we both raise the bar to win and the mean number of dics rolls by a factor two, but... at the same time the distribution get's more narrow.)

Comment: @BruceET well, it fits perfectly into a Bernoulli distribution, so that would be my guess…

Comment: @Sextus The post did not indicate how one might use the moments.  It's difficult to see how they are even relevant to the question.

Comment: @whuber I agree, it does not make a lot of sense. However the post does contain a format like *"**While** the expected Value of B is higher than A, the probability ...."*. So, by using the word '*while*' the OP explains which are the two different points of view. The expected value on the one hand and the probability on the other hand. But it is indeed not very clear. It is not made clear why the expected value - of the number of dice with a "6" - matters (so the post sort of indicates that the problem lies in that particulas aspect, although not very clear how exactly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $X$ of `6`'s in 4 trials has $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=4,p=1/6)$ and
he number $Y$ of `6`'s in 8 trials has $Y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=8,p=1/6).$

In R, $P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X = 0) = 0.5177.$

```
1-dbinom(0, 4, 1/6)
[1] 0.5177469
```

By contrast, $P(Y \ge 2) = 1 - P(X \le 1) = 0.3953,$ smaller than above.

```
1 - pbinom(1, 8, 1/6)
[1] 0.3953231
```

By simulation of a million games of each type:

```
set.seed(1120)
x = replicate(10^6,  sum(sample(1:6, 4, rep=T)==6))
mean(x >= 1)
[1] 0.517721     # aprx 0.5177

y = replicate(10^6,  sum(sample(1:6, 8, rep=T)==6))
mean(y >= 2)
[1] 0.395072      # aprx 0.3953 +/- 0.001
2*sd(y >= 2)/1000
[1] 0.0009777328  # 95% margin of simulation error
```

In each figure below, the histogram summarizes simulated values and the (centers of) red circles show exact binomial probabilities.

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 hist(x, prob=T, br = (-1:4)+.5, col="skyblue2")
  points(0:4, dbinom(0:4, 4, 1/6), col="red")
 hist(y, prob=T, br = (-1:8)+.5, col="skyblue2")
  points(0:8, dbinom(0:8, 8, 1/6), col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

***Bottom line:*** There are only $625$ chances in $1296$ to
lose the first game and $1\,015\,625$ chances in 
$1\,679\,616$ to lose the second.